# Recursive data retrieval from database in Zend framework similar to CakePHP

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

In **CakePHP**, we can provide **recursive** option while retrieving data from database, which automatically fetches the data from all the dependent tables.

We can also provide option for recursive e.g recursive=2, which fetches dependent tables of the dependent tables.

How can we achieve the same functionality in **Zend framework**?

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211032/recursive-option-like-cakephp-in-zend-framework)

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined Table Relationship on your model before, you can use `findDependentRowset()` to retrieve records from multiple related table. For more details, see [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html).

But i am not sure of limiting the recursion.